# jQuery toggle NextUntil parent tr of td with class

Tags: jquery, parent

I have a table that is generated with a toggle class on a td and a toggle-more class on following row td's.

I am trying to target the parent TR and use next until and then toggle the visibility of the following TR's after the td togglelink class and specify the nextuntil parent tr of the td toggle-more.

This is my table

```
<table  width=100% >
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="toggle">Agriculture</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="toggle-more" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aquaculture</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_1" value="110|Aquaculture">
          &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="toggle-more" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dairy Production</td>
        <td ><input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_2" value="120|Dairy Production">
          &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="toggle-more" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Horitculture</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_3" value="130|Horitculture">
          &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="toggle">Blah Blah</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr  class="toggle-more" >
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aquaculture</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_1" value="110|Aquaculture">
          &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
      </tr>
      <tr  class="toggle-more">
        <td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dairy Production</td>
        <td ><input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_2" value="120|Dairy Production">
          &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
      </tr>
      <tr  class="toggle-more">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Horitculture</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_3" value="130|Horitculture">
          &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="toggle">Blah Blah</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr  class="toggle-more" >
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aquaculture</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_1" value="110|Aquaculture">
          &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
      </tr>
      <tr  class="toggle-more">
        <td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dairy Production</td>
        <td ><input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_2" value="120|Dairy Production">
          &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
      </tr>
      <tr  class="toggle-more">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Horitculture</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_3" value="130|Horitculture">
          &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Health</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_16" value="1910|Dental">
          &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td >Dental</td>
        <td ><input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_16" value="1910|Dental">
          &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

and here is my jQuery.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var showText='+ Show Options';
var hideText='- Hide Options';
var is_visible = false;  

$('.toggle').wrapInner('<a href="#" class="toggleLink" />');
$('.toggleLink').append( ' <span class="showtext">'+showText+'</span>' );
$('.toggle').css({ 
        //width: '100%'
}); 
$('.toggle-more').closest( 'tr' ).hide();
$('a.toggleLink').click(function() {
    is_visible = !is_visible;
    $('.showtext').html( ($('.showtext').html() == hideText) ? showText : hideText);
    $(this).parents('tr').nextUntil('td:not(.toggle-more)').animate({ opacity: "toggle" });
    return false; 
});
});
```

It almost works. What am i doing wrong and is there a better way of doing this?

The past 2 rows are not toggles or have a toggle.

Comment: Sorry i meant last 2 rows are not part of the toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it comes to needing multiple table rows to represent one logical item, I'd suggest grouping those rows into `<tbody>` tags (yes it's perfectly valid HTML).

In doing so, you can scrap `.nextUntil()` in favour of the `.siblings()` method and in my opinion making it easier to play around with in jQuery.

JsFiddle : **[See Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/PXVNk/1/)**

HTML:

```
<table width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="toggle">Agriculture</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aquaculture</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_1" value="110|Aquaculture" />
                &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dairy Production</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_2" value="120|Dairy Production" />
                &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Horitculture</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_3" value="130|Horitculture" />
                &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="toggle">Blah Blah</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aquaculture</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_1" value="110|Aquaculture" />
                &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dairy Production</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_2" value="120|Dairy Production" />
                &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Horitculture</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_3" value="130|Horitculture" />
                &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Health</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_16" value="1910|Dental" />
                &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Dental</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_16" value="1910|Dental" />
                &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var showText='+ Show Options';
    var hideText='- Hide Options';

    $('.toggle').wrapInner('<a href="#" class="toggleLink" />');
    $('.toggleLink').append( ' <span class="showtext">'+showText+'</span>' );
    $('table tbody').each(function(){
        $(this).find('tr').not(':first').hide(); 
    });

    $('a.toggleLink').click(function() {
        var $a = $(this);
        $a.find('.showtext').html( ($a.find('.showtext').html() == hideText) ? showText : hideText);
        $a.closest('tr').siblings('tr').animate({ opacity: "toggle" });

        return false; 
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for: http://jsbin.com/equqaw/1/

As you could see [here](http://jsbin.com/equqaw/1/edit), I have made some changes in the markup and the jQuery.
All the `toggle` and `toggle-more` classes are now on the `tr`s and also the click function is slightly different now.

**Markup:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="toggle">
        <td>Agriculture</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle-more">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aquaculture</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_1" value="110|Aquaculture">
            &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle-more">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dairy Production</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_2" value="120|Dairy Production">
            &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle-more">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Horitculture</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_3" value="130|Horitculture">
            &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
        <td>Blah Blah</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle-more">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aquaculture</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_1" value="110|Aquaculture">
            &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle-more">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dairy Production</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_2" value="120|Dairy Production">
            &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle-more">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Horitculture</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_3" value="130|Horitculture">
            &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle">
        <td>Blah Blah</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle-more">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aquaculture</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_1" value="110|Aquaculture">
            &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle-more">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dairy Production</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_2" value="120|Dairy Production">
            &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toggle-more">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Horitculture</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_3" value="130|Horitculture">
            &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Health</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_16" value="1910|Dental">
            &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dental</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LookUpItem_16" value="1910|Dental">
            &nbsp;Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;Select</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var showText = '+ Show Options';
    var hideText = '- Hide Options';

    $('.toggle td:nth-child(2)').wrapInner('<a href="#" class="toggleLink" />');
    $('.toggleLink').append(' <span class="showtext">' + showText + '</span>');
    $('.toggle').css({
        //width: '100%'
    });
    $('.toggle-more').closest('tr').hide();
    $('a.toggleLink').click(function () {
        var showTextSpan = $(this).find('.showtext');
        showTextSpan.html((showTextSpan.html() == hideText) ? showText : hideText);
        $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:not(.toggle-more)').animate({
            opacity : "toggle"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Hope that helps. Feel free to ask any questions you have as comments...